# PHP not returning data value to jquery.ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following set of test files to send, and get an Ajax request/response between JS and PHP. The following are the files:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<!-- The result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#foo").submit(function(event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
                alert(data.returned_val);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $id = $_POST['bar'];
  echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => 'yoho'));
?>
```

**Steps to test:**

1. Open html in browser
2. Enter "testing"in text field
3. Click submit button

**Result:** alert box says: "undefined".

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think `below` belongs in your PHP. Do you get errors in your PHP? How do you test this?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. corrected. "below" was a typo while posting here. My code doesn't have it.

Comment: is `below` a typo? or really part of the script? or just part of the question? (meaning below the script). check the browser console (usually on network tab) if it is a `200`

Comment: Try visiting test.php without any parameters just to see if you're getting errors.

Comment: What say `console.log(data);`?

Comment: What is the `typeof data`? It may still be a `String` needing to be parsed (`data = $.parseJSON(data);`) as jQuery only auto-parses based on the `Content-Type`. Try either adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to the PHP or specify the `dataType: 'json'` for `$.ajax()`.

Comment: And instead of `alert(data.returned_val)`, it might be more helpful to do `console.log(data)` for debugging purposes.

Comment: No error, console.log is empty

Comment: What do you mean console.log is empty? Did you open your Javascript console?

Comment: Check you path `url: "test.php"` and check your post request `var_dump($_POST);` and check form realy submit or not add `alert('Submit')` after `$("#foo").submit(function(event) {`

Comment: console.log(data) output: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:9597
<?php
$id = $_POST['bar'];
//Code that would run here for whatever

// 1. Without JSON
//   echo "hello this is one"

// 2. By JSON. Then here is where I want to send a value back to the success of the Ajax below
echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => 'yoho'));
?>

Comment: @HamzaKubba before adding line console.log(data), console did not have any output

Comment: @Vindy If you're seeing `<?php $id = $_POST['bar']; ...` from `console.log(data)` in your browser's Console / Dev Tools, then PHP probably isn't enabled on your server. It would mean you're getting the raw code as text rather than the result from evaluating it.

Comment: Do you have PHP installed correctly? I already said this, but can you visit the `test.php` page in your browser and see what you get?

Comment: You may be missing something in your apache.conf or IIS configuration (or whatever web server config). Your web server is serving PHP files in plain text instead of 'running' them through PHP.

Comment: @HamzaKubba i opened test.php in browser and I can see the php code.

Comment: Yes, so your web server is not currently configured to run PHP. Google around to find out how to install and configure PHP with your web server.

Comment: Actually I don't even know if you have a web server?

Comment: Ah @HamzaKubba i think I understand now. thanks, will add it to apache config. Yes, I have apache installed that runs html and js. Never tried php before.

Comment: Cool... if you're using windows, consider using wamp. If you're using a mac, consider using mamp. (Google them).